# Running scala program from command line fails; pasting it into interpreter succeeds

Tags: scala

When I paste a code fragment into the scala interpreter, it works as
expected, but when I attempt to run the same file using

```
scala ./name-of-file.scala
```

It prints

```
<my hostname>: <my hostname>
```

I am on Fedora 11, and the Scala version I am using is 2.7.7final.

Comment: Knowing nothing about your problem - you didn't really tell us much - update to a newer version of Scala.

Comment: Can you ping your `hostname`? If you can't, fix it.

Comment: `scala -nocompdaemon` might work. but yeah, don't use Scala 2.7, it's ancient. use 2.9.1

Comment: scala is also generally used as a compiled language; the interpreter and REPL are just for convenience and poking around. Try compiling your program with scalac.

Comment: @Daniel if you could change your comment into an answer I would give you credit; the root cause was that my hostname was not specified in /etc/hosts.

Comment: This question is very unfairly downvoted. Sure, it _looks_ like there isn't enough information being provided, but that's mostly because Scala 2.7.x's error message for this situation was really awful. Not to say the question couldn't be better, but it isn't that bad.

Comment: Downvoters: any and all scala files were giving this message; supplying the particulars wouldn't have helped.  Upgrading didn't fix it either, but it gave a more detailed message (Java exception during hostname resolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does running the following command works?

```
ping `hostname`
```

If it doesn't, that's most likely your problem.

You see, because not only Scala programs run on JVM, but the Scala compiler itself runs on JVM, and the JVM has pretty steep starting times, when running scripts Scala keeps a copy of the compiler running in background as a daemon, and talks to it through a TCP connection.

Alas, it gets the IP address by resolving the hostname, which means any computer which has a hostname that is not associated to a valid IP address on that hostname will have problems.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel; that was the problem.  I had to update /etc/hosts with the name of my host; before this I just had it in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Comment: @Raphael - localhost is in the /etc/hosts file (by default), so ping localhost works.  I just had neglected to add my hostname alias to the /etc/hosts file.